# Start Angular watch without build

Tags: angular

Angular has a nice feature where it builds your project, watches for changes, and compiles just what has changed. Example:

`ng build --watch`

Suppose you want to just start watching again without building (because nothing has changed, maybe your laptop rebooted, etc). Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not understanding. Can you explain it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

The NRWL team has something that you may want to consider to achieve this.  They call it computational caching.  The idea is that it caches the output of previous commands and allows you to skip the computational operations.  It's supposed to be a huge time saver, particularly on large projects.

I haven't used it myself, but if you want to read up on it, here's the documentation:
https://nx.dev/angular/tutorial/10-computation-caching

If you've never heard of NRWL, these guys make some premium Angular and React tooling.